# What happens when you move a website that uses django-social-auth to sign in?

Tags: django, openid

I've been developing a Django site that uses `django-social-auth` ([this one](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)) for login, more specifically the Livejournal backend. We're looking at using other services to log in in future, but LJ (which I believe is pretty much OpenID) is the one we care about most right now.

We're setting up on Dreamhost right now (which is a problem in itself, but I don't have a choice about it for the moment), but it's not the most Django-friendly host and there's a fairly high chance we'll be moving servers in the near future, which may be with the same or a different URL. I don't know the details of OpenID implementation, and I'm concerned that this may break user logins. If I move my site to a different server/address, will user logins still be connected to the correct accounts, or is there some secret key link that will be broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Facebook or Twitter you'll have to change your callback url for your app, but ONLY if you're changing the site address. If you're keeping the site address the same I don't think you'll have any issues.

Comment: Once that's changed, there should be no problems with breaking user accounts? And I won't have to change anything with OpenID?

Comment: Correct. The only change would be the callback, if the site url changes.